# Block user navigation in a Pivot item for UWP apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

How can you block a user from clicking on a Pivot item in a UWP XAML app but still show the heading for each pivot item? For example, I have three pivot items that are labeled "Step 1", "Step 2", and "Step 3". I want each of those items to show up at the top of the pivot table, but not be user engagable. They are only there to proivde awarness to the users current location in a process.

I have tried `IsLocked="true"` in the definition of the pivot table, but it only shows me the title for the pivot item I am currently on.

Answer (score 1):

I tried IsEnabled="false" and that didn't work.  Then I tried data binding to a property and used the setter to restrict its value, and that did work.

View:

```
<Pivot SelectedIndex="{x:Bind PageViewModel.MyPivotIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <PivotItem Header="Item1">
        <TextBlock Text="Stuff1"/>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Item2" IsEnabled="False">
        <TextBlock Text="Stuff2"/>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

ViewModel:

```
private int _myPivotIndex;
public int MyPivotIndex
{
    get
    {
        return _myPivotIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        if (ConditionMet)
        {
            _myPivotIndex = value;
        }
        else
        {
            _myPivotIndex = 0;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyPivotIndex");
        }
    }
}
```

A non-MVVM option that should work is if you used the "SelectionChanged" event in the code-behind to check a condition and then if need be set it back to Item1 by setting SelectedItem or SelectedIndex.

If you want the "disabled" items to not highlight on mouse-over, you'll have to copy the style (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx) and modify it in the the "PointerOver" Visual State.